# couchbase PHP bulk insert

Tags: php, couchbase

I am having trouble bulk inserting documents with the PHP SDK.  I have to insert each one individually like

```
$temp = $db->upsert("key here", "value here");
```

I can achieve about 500 / second.  I have attempted to use the cbcdocloader but I cant generate json faster than just using the SDK to insert them directly.  I am trying to insert multiple documents with one insert so I dont have to generate all the traffic.  Is there a way to do this with an array structure like below?

```
 $data = array("key 1"=> "value 1", "key 2" => "value 2")
```

Answer (score 2):

I just did not believe it as I stumbled upon it somewhere a time ago, when I was searching for something else... But now I tried it, and it seems to work and I got a great performance increase (when doing a lot of inserts). It seems, you have to do it that way (using SDK 2.0 and `upsert()`):

```
$bucket->upsert(array(
    'key1' => array('value' => 'value1'),
    'key2' => array('value' => array('jsonkey' => 'jsonvalue')));
```

You have to use `'value'` literally in the second array.

It seems, you also can specify options using:

```
$bucket->upsert(array(...), null, array('expiry' => 3600));
```

Maybe someone can verify this...

Answer (score 0):

There is no bulk upload api call as such.

There is a semo of inserting in bulk http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.1/#performing-a-bulk-set.

Even, this does what you are already doing, in loops.